# Link Excel workbooks so that I can use them on another computer (Excel 2011 for Mac)

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, links

We have an Excel spreadsheet that uses data from another workbook.

We use Dropbox to share the files.

When I open the spreadsheet on another Mac or PC the links need relinking.

Is there a way to make the links reference just the immediate folder?

Here's the problem explained further.

> Workbook contains a link to: ***~my-mac/dropbox/work/source.xlsx***
>
> It doesn't work when opened on: ***~ãnother-mac/dropbox/work/source.xlsx***
>
> I want Excel 2011 for Mac just to look for ***~/dropbox/work/source.xlsx***

I've read several help pages on Absoulte links and relative links and UNC links.
It seems it is possible to link workbooks using the short link, however, I am unable to make it work.

Is it a Mac thing? Is it a me thing?

Any potshots from hotshots most welcome!

J

Comment: excel stores relative links only when the path is on the same drive. see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328440) for further info

Answer (score 2):

This VBA code will update the links to the immediate folder, provided your file only links to one other book:

```
Sub DropBox()

    Dim vOldLink As Variant, sOldLink As String
    vOldLink = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    sOldLink = vOldLink(1)

    Dim vFilename As Variant, sFilename As String
    vFilename = Split(sOldLink, "\")
    sFilename = vFilename(UBound(vFilename))

    Dim sPath
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=sOldLink, NewName:=sPath & sFilename, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

End Sub
```

I am not sure about Mac though...

Comment: Thanks for that.
Will try it out but unfortunately the workbook links to 3 other workbooks.